# Ansible turn files item into strings

Tags: python-3.x, loops, filter, ansible, jinja2

Im trying to find a clean way of converting a files list into a path(string) list.
So far i came up with this:

```
- name: Get apt source files
  find:
    paths: /etc/apt/sources.list.d
    use_regex: yes
    patterns: '^.*\.list$'
  register: source_files

- name: loop trough source files 
  when:
    - item != SOME_VAR
    - DO_CLEAN_UP
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    regexp: "^deb {{ REPO_CLEAN_URL }}" # set in vars/main.yml
    state: absent
  with_items: 
      - /etc/apt/sources.list
      - "{{ source_files.files | items2dict(key_name='path', value_name='path') | list }}"
```

I would like to improve the "with_items" part please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as file-object in Ansible playbooks, you only work with basic data types supported by YAML/JSON: string, list, mapping (dictionary), integer and boolean.

When in doubt make use of `debug` module to display variables and how jinja2 constructs are evaluated, works well even with loops.

Comment: Hey, im sorry i should have said a file list, which in ansible terms means a single dict object describing a file.

Comment: But that unfortunately does not solve my question.